# In this main object how do I get all cars model value

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object

```
const cars={
    cars1:{
        name:"Suzuki",
        model:565,
        price:1200
    },
    cars2:{
        name:"hyundai",
        model:567,
        price:1300
    },
    cars3:{
        name:"toyata",
        model:897,
        price:2000
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you show what you have tried so that we can offer you some help?

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the object keys and return the `name` node of all keys.

```js
const cars = {
    cars1: {
        name: "Suzuki",
        model: 565,
        price: 1200
    },
    cars2: {
        name: "hyundai",
        model: 567,
        price: 1300
    },
    cars3: {
        name: "toyata",
        model: 897,
        price: 2000
    }
}
const carModels = Object.keys(cars).map((key) => cars[key].name);
console.log(carModels);
```